# How to best load many database entries in single transaction?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I'm using `Spring` with `Hibernate`, and want to update a private cache 2-3 times a day. Each update will be having like 100.000 entries.

How could I best perform such operations? I have to execute this in a single transaction so that I do not have outdated and updates entries at once in the meantime of persisting the new data.

My database is SQL `postres`. Could you recommend on this?

Comment: Execute the query and iterate through the result set. What is there to tell?

Comment: The thing I will suggest you is to remove `hibernate` and use `mybatis` as fixed SQL can enhance the sql performance in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate has some recommendations for [batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) which may be useful for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of processing, a good idea may be to update the cache using a stored procedure in postgres itself. It will give you the best performance possible. And all you have to do in your app is to call the procedure.